# Angular unknown provider and Cannot POST /signup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Before you say anything, I know the solution probably is to inject the dependency but I checked other open source codes and compare it with mine, it is exactly the same. While theirs work while mine's not working

Currently the problem is at route '/signup'

I got **Error: error:unpr
Unknown Provider** when I check the console at route '/signup' and

Whenever I go to '/signup' route and press submit button it supposed to hit the api and redirect to '/' but what I got instead is Cannot POST /signup.

The api works just fine when I used POSTMAN, I assume the problem is with angular.

index.html ( Does the order of the script is important? )

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <base href='/'> 
    <!-- load bootstrap from CDN and custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/userController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/services/factories.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'

            })

            .when('/signup', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/signup.html',
                controller: 'SignUpController'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
    })
```

userController.js

```
 angular.module('MyApp')

    .controller('SignUpController', function($scope, User) {


        // sign up the user
        $scope.signup = function() {

            User.create({
                name: $scope.name,
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            });

        }


    });
```

factories.js

```
angular.module('MyApp')

.factory('User', function($http, $alert, $window, $location) {


    var userFactory = {};

    userFactory.create = function(userData) {
        return $http.post('/api/signup', userData)
            .then(function(data) {
                $window.localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                $location.path('/');
            });
    }


    return userFactory;

});
```

signup.html

```
<div class="span3 well">
      <legend>New to Project626? Sign up!</legend>
    <form method="post" ng-submit="signup()">
        <input class="span3" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" ng-model="name"> 
        <input class="span3" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" ng-model="username">
        <input class="span3" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" ng-model="password"> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up for Project626</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I like this way of writing angular because its way cleaner for me. For your information the open source that I mention above is https://github.com/sahat/tvshow-tracker/blob/master/public/controllers/signup.js

Comment: Hey can you provide error in detail I mean "Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider " pelase paste few more lines of error.

Comment: this is what I got, https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=

Answer (score 1):

Youd didn't add

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Order must be this :

```
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app/services/factories.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/userController.js"></script>
```

That's why it is showing unknown provider for route.

Comment: For simplicity I took out the main files of angular, angular-route etc to focus on the main problem. Since you said it, I probably need to edit my question

Comment: What do you think? did I miss anything?

Comment: yes order ,the factories must be load before controller because controller has dependency of factories.

Comment: Tried it and the error still persist, if you check this link and scroll down. The order is controller first then service second https://github.com/sahat/tvshow-tracker/blob/master/public/index.html

Comment: Is it okay if i push this to github and let you take a look at it?