# Cannot POST /index.html in AngularJS error in localhost whereas works fine on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, localhost, http-post

I am currently working AmgularJS project, I am successfully sign-in in Homeview when I host project over Amazon server whereas it din't works in localhost.

**App.js** is something like this :

```js
//Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('blickbeeLite', [ 'ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http)
{
});

app.config(['$provide', '$routeProvider', function ($provide, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      })
      .when('/:templateFile', {
        templateUrl: function (param) { return 'views/'+param.templateFile+'.html' }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

and error is :

**Cannot POST /index.html**

Comment: What http server software do toy run locally

Comment: I am using Brackets IDE for development of AngularJS. and usually use "Live Preview" and alternative is "XAMPP".
Thanks, issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included 'angular-route.js' in your html??
Similar question

[Angular unknown provider and Cannot POST /signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403502/angular-unknown-provider-and-cannot-post-signup)

Comment: Its get worked !!I Actually, I didn't think issue with angular-route.js because it was already included.

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>